# SSH known hosts in Windows (Error code = 124)

Tags: parallelization, remote-access

I had to re-install Raspbian OS and now it has new SSH key. SSH clients usually let ignore this fact and save the new key, but not now. 
Mathematica gives no way to go if the Host Key was changed. I get an error

```
SSH received a different Host Key while launching kernel 'Raspberry Pi'. Error code = 124.
```

when trying to start remote kernel and I have found no any information about where is the Mathematica's SSH client on Windows... I just need to clear known hosts... 
The easy way is to change Raspberry's IP, but it's far less interesting, moreover not always possible

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question, and maybe describe the answer in a little more detail.  It will be useful for other people who run into the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Solution found using ProcMon and is That Simple!

C:\Users\%USERNAME%\.ssh

So if you have the same problem, then just open the file C:\Users\%USERNAME%\.ssh\known_hosts using any notepad and delete the entity with the outdated key. Restart Mathematica and try to connect to the remote ketnel. The new key will be created.