# Remote Kernel configuration works in v9 but not in v10

Tags: kernel, windows, remote-access, raspberry-pi

I have both v9 and v10 currently installed on my computer (Windows 7).  For reasons that are not entirely clear, if I create a new remote kernel in one version, it is accessible to the other; **however**, there are differences.  Note the following screen shot:

[image]

The picture above shows the kernel properties for the same kernel connection when viewed in v9 (left) or v10 (right).  The results are the same regardless of whether I initially create the new kernel connection in v9 or v10.  Note that the shell commands are different for the two versions:

#### v9

> "`java`" -jar "`mathssh`" pi@raspilab wolfram -mathlink -LinkMode Connect -LinkProtocol TCPIP -LinkName "`linkname`" -LinkHost `ipaddress`

#### v10

> "`java`" -jar "`wolframssh`" pi@raspilab wolfram -wstp -LinkMode Connect -LinkProtocol TCPIP -LinkName "`linkname`" -LinkHost `ipaddress`

**The problem is:** the remote kernel works properly in v9 but not v10.  In v10, I get the error message "SSH's connection for kernel 'rpi_kernel' was unexpectedly terminated. Error code = 103."

I don't believe this is a [known hosts](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43634/7167) problem.  Removing the known_hosts file does not change the behavior in v10 (it still throws the 103 error) but causes v9 to request that the new host be added and the known_hosts file be created.  No wolfram processes are currently active on the RPi and I have turned off my VPN to [avoid a previous problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/65767/7167).  If I use the advanced options to force the v10 Shell command to look like that for v9, I get the same 103 error code.  If I do the reverse, and use the v10 command in v9, I get an Error code = 1 [for which there seems to be no good solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21231/7167).

Some additional debugging information:

- Based on the speed at which the 103 error is returned, I suspect that v10 is not even attempting to connect to the RPi kernel.
- Using the RPi's IP address instead of its hostname does not alter the results.

Does anyone have any insight into resolving this problem?

Comment: Have you tried using a different ssh binary instead of `wolframssh` (probably needs to be specified with the full absolute path?

Comment: @shrx a good suggestion and I will try that soon.  I did try the complete v9 command but since I didn't put a full path in, there's no reason to think it would have worked properly.

Comment: @shrx no luck.  I can substitute the full path of wolframssh in the v9 kernel configuration; but the same does not hold true for v10 (either the path of the v10 wolframssh or the v9 version of the jar file)

Comment: The wolframssh.jar file in 10.0.1 and 10.0.2 is broken.  I can't tell from your last comment if you tried using the v9 version of wolframssh with a v10 kernel, but that method works with my windows 8 machine.  Also, you could try doing simpler commands (e.g., pwd, ls) to help with debugging:
Run["java -jar pathto/WolframSSH.jar pi@raspilab pwd"]

Comment: @chadk Thanks for the comment.  I'll spend some more time trying the v9 wolframssh with v10 now that I know someone has gotten that to work.

Comment: @ChadK your suggestion works - can you please post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The WolframSSH.jar file in 10.0.1 and 10.0.2 is broken. In fact, WolframSSH.jar has not accepted alternate locations for the keyfile locations (and I don't know what the default directories are that it searches) since before version 8.

So there are 2 possible solutions.  One is to use the v9 version of WolframSSH.jar.  The other (and the one I recommend) is to install cygwin and use its ssh (which will have a path like c:\cygwin64\bin\ssh).

Mathematica 10 has new process functions that can be used to test connections to remote machines.  To test an ssh connection, you could try this:

```
process = StartProcess[$SystemShell];
cmd = "\\cygwin64\\bin\\ssh me@machinename ls";
WriteLine[process, cmd]
ReadLine[process] (* evaluate this multiple times to see line by line output *)
```

Import could also be used here (and for this case is much simpler):

```
Import["!" <> cmd, "Text"]
```

The StartProcess function is more useful when linking to a kernel.  Here is some code that I've used to launch a remote kernel and perform evaluations:

Preliminaries (note that my math script is in my path, so I don't give full path in  mathl function):

```
    mathl[link_] := 
  "math -mathlink -linkmode Connect -linkprotocol TCPIP -linkname "<>link <> " -subkernel -noinit &< /dev/null &";
    machine = "mymachine";
    link = LinkCreate[LinkProtocol -> "TCPIP"];
    linkname = First@link;
    cmd = "\\cygwin64\\bin\\ssh " <> $UserName <> "@" <> machine <> 
       " \"" <> mathl[linkname] <> "\"";
```

Processes:

```
process = StartProcess[$SystemShell];
WriteLine[process, cmd];
```

That should have launched a remote kernel.  You can check with ps, taskmanager, etc.  Better yet, try to communicated with the remote kernel:

```
LinkWrite[link, Unevaluated@{$MachineName, Now}];
In[150]:= LinkRead[link]
Out[150]= InputNamePacket["In[1]:= "]
In[151]:= LinkRead[link]
Out[151]= ReturnPacket[{"mymachine", DateObject[{2015, 2, 9}, TimeObject[{14, 55, 49.3625}, TimeZone -> -6.], TimeZone -> -6.]}]
```

Finally, close the link and the process:

```
LinkClose[link]
KillProcess[process]
```

Comment: Do you happen to know if WolframSSH.jar is still broken in newer versions of MMA and whether this is a Windows only issue?

Comment: I apologize for taking so long to respond.  I really don't know the answer to either with certainty.  I find that using the ssh with cygwin works nicely for me.  I cannot get WolframSSH.jar to work correctly [yet!].  If I find a way to make it work, I'll post here.  Note:  I'm using 10.3

Comment: no problem, thank you for your response.