# Remote Raspberry Pi Kernel from 2nd Raspberry Pi Front End

Tags: parallelization, remote-access, raspberry-pi

I've reviewed the following posts:

[Connecting two Raspberry Pi's using MathLink](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/216742?p_p_auth=XPByFH4N)

[remote kernel through SSH](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65953/remote-kernel-through-ssh)

[How to connect the front end of one raspberry pi with the kernel of another](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/76459/how-to-connect-the-front-end-of-one-raspberry-pi-with-the-kernel-of-another)

But have been unsuccessful in launching a remote kernel on a Pi from another Pi's front end.

I completed step 1 from the last referenced post and can access the remote Pi without a password using the terminal window but every other step fails once confined to the front end.

```
mathl[link_] := "wolfram -mathlink -linkmode Connect -linkprotocol TCPIP 
 -linkname " <> link <> " -subkernel -noinit &< /dev/null &";
machine = "169.254.160.100";
link = LinkCreate[LinkProtocol -> "TCPIP"];
linkname = First@link;
cmd = "ssh " <> $UserName <> "@" <> machine <> " \"" <> mathl[linkname] <> "\"";
```

The link created is `127.0.0.1` which doesn't work and seems wrong so I forced it to use the following:

```
mathl[link_] := "wolfram -mathlink -linkmode Connect -linkprotocol TCPIP 
 -linkname " <> link <> " -subkernel -noinit &< /dev/null &";
machine = "169.254.160.100";
link = LinkCreate["@169.254.160.120,@169.254.160.120,",LinkProtocol -> "TCPIP"];
linkname = First@link;
cmd = "ssh " <> $UserName <> "@" <> machine <> " \"" <> mathl[linkname] <> "\"";
```

`169.254.160.100` is the remote Pi and `169.254.160.120` is the local Pi

No matter what I try it seems to hang on `LinkWrite[link,Unevaluated@{$MachineName,Now[]}];` of

```
process = StartProcess[$SystemShell];
    WriteLine[process,cmd];
    LinkWrite[link,Unevaluated@{$MachineName,Now[]}];
LinkRead@link
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that [remote kernel through SSH](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65953/remote-kernel-through-ssh) was the most useful guide. Setting up the remote Kernels manually was more succsessful compared to using `FrontEndTokenExecute["PreferencesDialog"]`

In addition, I connected the boards using the on-board wireless as opposed to the LAN connection which for some reason helped.

The following code launches 4 local and 4 remote Kernels (assuming you've done `ssh-keygen`, `ssh-copy-id pi@<remote>` - [reference](https://linuxconfig.org/passwordless-ssh)):

```
Needs["SubKernels`RemoteKernels`"]

Parallel`Palette`menuStatus[]
LaunchKernels[4]

user = "pi";
machine = "<remote ip>";
number = 4;(*number of parallel kernels to launch*)

ssh = "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=;ssh";
mathl[link_] := "wolfram" <> " -mathlink -linkmode Connect `4` 
                -linkname `2` -subkernel -noinit >& /dev/null &";

remote = SubKernels`RemoteKernels`RemoteMachine[machine, 
  ssh <> " " <> user <> "@" <> machine <> " \"" <> mathl[linkname] <> 
   "\"", number]

Print[remote // InputForm]
kerns = LaunchKernels[remote]

ParallelEvaluate[$MachineName]
```

The following maxes all cores on both local and remote:

```
ParallelTable[Prime[100000000000], {8}];
```

Now that this works, I'm adding two more remote Pi boards to use the full 16 Kernel license!