# Setting up parallel remote kernels

Tags: parallelization, remote-access, kernel-startup

I'm having trouble setting-up a parallel remote kernel.
I have correctly set-up remote kernels and can use them instead of the local kernels, by executing `tunnel.sh` script as explained [here](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/321179)

However I can't manage to use remote parallel kernels in addition to the local kernels.
I tried to use the `WolframSSH.jar` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783840/how-to-configure-parallel-remote-kernels-in-mathematica)

`MathKernel` process is launched, but dies after a few second of freeze.

Then I tried with :

```
LaunchKernels[
     SubKernels`RemoteKernels`RemoteMachine["remote", 
          "ssh -v remoteuser@remoteIP math -mathlink -linkmode Connect \
          `4` -linkname `2` -subkernel -noinit 1>out.txt 2>err.txt"
     ]
]
```

The `MathKernel` process launches on the remote machine, but dies straight away

The `out.txt` output is then:

> LinkConnect::linkc:     -- Message text not found -- (
>       LinkObject[46644@remoteIP,52289@remoteIP, 3, 1])

The `err.txt` output is then:

> debug1: Sending command: math -mathlink -linkmode Connect
>   -linkprotocol TCPIP -linkname 46644@remoteIP,52289@remoteIP -subkernel -noinit debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0 debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1 debug1:
>   fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK debug1: fd 2
>   clearing O_NONBLOCK Transferred: sent 3232, received 2412 bytes, in
>   0.3 seconds Bytes per second: sent 12332.3, received 9203.4 debug1: Exit status 1

Local and remote machine are running Mathematica 10.0 under Linux (Ubuntu). I'm not using a VPN but just ssh connection.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Tell us about your infrastructure configuration, including number of processors; types of machines and operating systems (local and remote); network (including your local and remote networks, and what VPN you use if any); number of Mma licenses; license versions.  Best to add all of this to your question.

Comment: [Somewhat related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69411/7167). Note that WolframSSH.jar in v10 seems to have some problems with it.

Answer (score 3):

I've solved the problem by using the `tunnel_sub.sh` from Sacha Kratky script provided [here](http://www.unisoftwareplus.com/download/Tunnel.zip). Thank you

Comment: The Tunnel scripts are now hosted at [GitHub](https://github.com/sakra/Tunnel).

Comment: The tunneling works perfectly here. Windows - Windows setup. Thanks.